# Rescale predictions of regression model fitted on scaled predictors

Tags: r, regression, prediction

Let's say I fit a model to data that has been standardized to z-score form:

```
#load data
data(cars)

#standardize variables so that they have mean 0 and st. dev 1
st.cars <- scale(cars)
st.cars <- as.data.frame(st.cars)

mod <- lm(speed ~ dist,data=st.cars)
```

I would like to make predictions using this model:

`predict(mod,st.cars)`, however, I would like to get the predictions on the original scale of the dependent variable in the dataset.

Is there a way to re-scale the predictions to the original scale?

Answer (score 10):

The `scale` function stores the `scale` and `center` values it uses to scale the data in an attribute. These can be used to convert predictions on the scaled data back to the original data scale.

```
# Scale cars data:
scars <- scale(cars)
# Save scaled attibutes:
scaleList <- list(scale = attr(scars, "scaled:scale"),
    center = attr(scars, "scaled:center"))
# scars is a matrix, make it a data frame like cars for modeling:
scars <- as.data.frame(scars) 
smod <- lm(speed ~ dist, data = scars)
# Predictions on scaled data:
sp <- predict(smod, scars)
# Fit the same model to the original cars data:
omod <- lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
op <- predict(omod, cars)
# Convert scaled prediction to original data scale:
usp <- sp * scaleList$scale["speed"] + scaleList$center["speed"]
# Compare predictions:
all.equal(op, usp)
```

If you want to use the model to predict new data with the `smod` model object, you will need to scale the newdata values using the appropriate values from the `scaleList` object (do not call the `scale` function on the newdata directly).

Comment: R should include some automatic and way to reverse standardization on the output. Something working for different models (logistic, linear...) and for other statistics (Coefficients, Intercept...).

Answer (score 4):

I have built on skaluzny's answer, if you want a more intuitive way to do this, without saving the scale attributes, but rather using knowledge of what the scale() function does by default (you really only need the last couple lines of this answer).

The scale function centers (subtracts mean value), and then scales (divides by standard deviation of data):

```
sdist <- scale(cars$dist)
head(sdist)

           [,1]
[1,] -1.5902596
[2,] -1.2798136
[3,] -1.5126481
[4,] -0.8141446
[5,] -1.0469791
[6,] -1.2798136

sdist2<-(cars$dist-mean(cars$dist))/sd(cars$dist)
head(sdist2)

[1] -1.5902596 -1.2798136 -1.5126481 -0.8141446 -1.0469791 -1.2798136
# Note this only is oriented the other way because scale() function outputs a matrix:

sdist2<-as.matrix(sdist2)
head(sdist2)
# The output now looks identical

           [,1]
[1,] -1.5902596
[2,] -1.2798136
[3,] -1.5126481
[4,] -0.8141446
[5,] -1.0469791
[6,] -1.2798136
```

So instead of storing things as a list, we can actually use the mean and standard deviation of the *original* data.

```
# Scale cars data:
scars <- scale(cars)

# Save scaled attibutes:
scaleList <- list(scale = attr(scars, "scaled:scale"),
                  center = attr(scars, "scaled:center"))

scaleList
$`scale`
    speed      dist 
 5.287644 25.769377 

$center
speed  dist 
15.40 42.98 

> sapply(cars,mean) # note that these values are the same as the `center` values above
speed  dist 
15.40 42.98

> sapply(cars,sd)  # note that these values are the same as the `scale` values above
    speed      dist 
 5.287644 25.769377
```

So now we can check if the predicted values would all be the same if we just use `mean()` and `sd()` rather than scale attributes:

```
# scars is a matrix, make it a data frame like cars for modeling:
scars <- as.data.frame(scars) 
smod <- lm(speed ~ dist, data = scars)

# Predictions on scaled data:
sp <- predict(smod, scars)

# Fit the same model to the original cars data:
omod <- lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
op <- predict(omod, cars)

# Now the original answer was to use these stored attributes to modify the predictions:
usp1 <- sp * scaleList$scale["speed"] + scaleList$center["speed"]

# We can also simply use the standard deviation and mean from the original dataset:
usp2 <- sp * sd(cars$speed) + mean(cars$speed)

identical(usp1,usp2)
[1] TRUE

all.equal(op, usp1, usp2)
[1] TRUE
```

This might be faster / more efficient if you do it this way since there is no need to create extra dataframes / objects:

```
Mod <- lm(scale(speed) ~ scale(dist), data = cars) # add scale() function directly to model

Unscaled_Pred <- predict(Mod, cars) * sd(cars$speed) + mean(cars$speed)


all.equal(op, Unscaled_Pred)
[1] TRUE                      # predictions are the same as the model that was never scaled
```